# Ending terminal application on mac + cleanup process

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory

I am trying to create a c program which has an infinite loop in the main method (multi-threaded application). We are using pthreads and POSIX shared memory between two applications. If I exit one of the programs using the command line (CTL+C), then I want to run a cleanup method to cleanup all allocated memory and removed the POSIX shared memory map.

```
int main () {
    for (;;)
    {
    }
    
        destroy_shared_object(shm, MEM_MAP_SIZE);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        return 0;
}
```

Right now this is what I have above, however when I exit the program I don't think it removes the shared memory map and cleans up. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can catch `CTRL+C` with `signal()`.

Answer (score 1):

You may catch `CTRL+C` with a [`signal()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) handler and set a flag variable within the signal handler:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t running = 1;

void sighandler(int signum) {
   running = 0;
}

int main() {
   signal(SIGINT, sighandler);

   while(running) {
      sleep(1); 
   }

   printf("Do the cleanup...\n");

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

It's probably better to use [`sigaction()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead:

> ```
>   WARNING: the behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions,
>   and has also varied historically across different versions of
>   Linux.  Avoid its use: use sigaction(2) instead.  See > Portability
>   below.
> ```

Comment: The code in your answer is dangerous. Neither of the functions you call in `sighandler` are async-signal-safe.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thank you! I have adjusted my answer, I hope it's safe now.

Comment: Better, but still slightly wrong. Your `bool` needs to be changed to `sig_atomic_t`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Alright :D Thanks, didn't know that there is a typedef for an atomic integer type (in the context of signal handling).